# SAP HANA VORA accessing Hadoop data

Tags: vora

can someone guide me with some references on how SAP HANA VORA access data from Hadoop. Would be good, if someone can refer me some documentation/video on this area.

Regards
Giri

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple resources available.

If you're looking to install Vora you can refer to the official Vora installation guide, or if you've already installed Vora and want some hands-on exercises you can refer to the developer guide. Both are available at SAP's website.

SAP also released a free online course on Introduction to Vora 1.2 last September which is available at [open.sap.com](https://open.sap.com/courses/hsvo1) and finally there are [hands-on tutorial videos available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkzo92owKnVw4Ax5YsW66pwEXI3AwaEcg).